# RubyOnRails Auto submit when changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added this:

```
onchange: 'this.form.submit();'
```

to this:

```
<%= f.select :rank, 1..3, {}, {class: 'form-control selectpicker', data: {'live-search' => 'true'}, onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %>
```

and I'm getting this error message:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in PlanController#create_or_update
```

but when when I go back my list is updated with my selection, so it is working??
How do I fix this?

These are the lines that are causing the error...

```
if success
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { @attempted_update ? render('sample_update') : render('sample_create') }
      end
    else
      @model = @sample_model
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { redirect_to sample_path(sample_name_1: session[:sample_name2]), notice: render_to_string('sample_plan2') }
      end
```

Comment: I guess 'this.form.submit();' requests an html response.  I think you need to change your form so that it requests js using "remote: true" or "local: false" depending which form builder you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not specified the html format in respond to. You only specify format.js but when you run your web application from a web browser you have to specify format.html, too, because that's the format the client expects.

Something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to sample_path, notice: 'Record successfully created.'}
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I this helped submit the form but now im running into an issue where it's submitting it twice it seems. 
Should I add this into an if statement or an els-if? I've tried doing and if statement with a conditional or, another with a conditional and but nothing has fixed it so far.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related with respond_to. How did you realize that the form submits twice?

Comment: So after I press the return button it will add the new record to the list but will then will reload the page almost immediately afterward and will have the record listed twice.

Comment: I looked it my working tree in GIT and I had code saved in my js file that I thought I deleted. Your code was the solution.